# Magento 2 Need Multiple coupon codes to be applied for order

Tags: magento2, magento2.2

There are two items in my shopping cart, and I need to do is apply 15% discount to one of the cart item AND apply 40% discount on the other cart item.Can anyone let me know that is it possible in Magento 2 ?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

```
Yes it is Possible 
1. Category Condition
2. Attribute Set Condition
```

Answer (score 1):

Even though Magento 2 allows you to create multiple coupons, you cannot redeem more than 1 coupon per transaction.

You can provide those discounts by creating specific rules in one coupon. Not using coupons separately at the same time.